# How to Intent Dynamically generated EditText data in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-edittext

I am able to generate multiple editText dynamically,
but don't understand how to intent its text on Next activity by using intent

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

    }
public void onDelete(View v) {
        parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
    }
```

Comment: What actually you want to say? Your code tell different story

Comment: Please provide id for each editText and get the data from each editText using this id.

Comment: onAddField() this create editText Dynamically , suppose i created 10 editText and type text on it , now i have to intent this data on other activity.

Comment: `now i have to intent this data on other activity` did you mean call it or sending it via Intent?

Comment: ישו אוהב אותך Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add all editexts to on list..

```
List<EditText> edt_all = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

and then you will getdata

```
for(int i=0; i < edt_all.size(); i++){
    string[i] = edt_all.get(i).getText().toString();
    Log.e("##edittext ", string[i])
}
```

Comment: @V-rund Puro-hit Where you have used EditText in this code? which contain User input data.?

Comment: I just edited that answer dear. its actually @PNR 's answer